# Function in SQL PLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Can anyone help me to find the error!

```
SQL>  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pri
   2    (name MENU.ITEM_NAME%TYPE,QUANTITY IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
   3    pri MENU.ITEM_PRICE%TYPE ;
   4  BEGIN
   5    SELECT ITEM_PRICE
   6    INTO   pri
   7    FROM   MENU
   8    WHERE  ITEM_NAME = name;
   9    RETURN  (pri*QUANTITY) ;
   10 END get_pri;
   11 /

   Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: `show error;` and see what it says

Comment: Before you worry too much about this particular function, it would be good to become familiar with displaying compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

The function code appears correct.

So, we have to suspect the table and column references. Is there a table `MENU` in the schema in which you are trying to compile this function? If it is in another schema, you must prefix the table name with the schema name.

Then - does the table `MENU` have columns `ITEM_NAME` and `ITEM_PRICE`?

Of course, I didn't have a table `MENU` in my schema. After I created one, with two columns, `ITEM_NAME` and `ITEM_PRICE`, I was able to compile your function without errors, so it is almost certain this is the issue.